# Red Squiggly Lines Appearing Beneath ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I've got `ZipFile` method I've been using but it's not working anymore. The code does not compile and there are red squiggly lines everywhere. What am I doing wrong? When I place my mouse over the red parts, it usually tells me what's going wrong, but I have triple-checked everything and I still don't see the problem.

The red squiggly line is beneath `ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory...`

Comment: You'll have to add a reference to the `System.IO.Compression` assembly, and also add a `using System.IO.Compression;` statement in your code.

Comment: Tx for the quick reponse. I am trying your code now. I am only new to WPF. So sorry if this is a newb question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a using directive to the top of your file:

```
using System.IO.Compression;
```

And, since I'm not sure what code you're using, this is how you can extract a Zip File:

```
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(sourceFilePath, destinationPath);
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that! It was working before! I don't know how I manadged to delete that using statement. And tha k you for the code too it is working now.

Comment: @RǢF I'm glad it helped. Don't forget to mark the answer as 'accepted', so that others who visit this page know what worked for you.